# Partitioning problem after i updated ubuntu

Tags: boot

After i updated ubuntu i get this error message please help.
error: no such partition.grub rescue > I cant get anything to work please help.
I have tried the 1s up to 5

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest fix is to boot using an Ubuntu DVD or Flash Drive, backup anything important to you and do a re-install...